# What is the reason for not using action.defer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alt

In the [Alt Actions Docs](http://alt.js.org/docs/actions/) for `action.defer` it is written

> This is a method that faciliates calling multiple actions in another action. Since multiple actions cannot be fired until the dispatch loop has finished this helper function waits for the dispatch loop to finish and then fires off the action. It is not recommended but it is available anyway.

What I'm wondering about is **Why is it not recommended to use** `action.defer`? and what is the best practice for calling multiple actions asynchronously, one after the other?